# Database showing a list of current vulnerabilities?

Tags: security, firewall, vulnerabilities

I have been recently building my own firewall, but I was wondering is there a website or database which lists majority of the known vulnerabilities so I could obviously update my firewall based on the list?

Comment: Please specify on the **type of firewall** in development & the _steps you have already tried_ for collecting vulnerability-Defenitions.

Comment: I am currently using an NIDS called SNORT, in terms of finding vulnerbabilties, I have tried to look for some credible databases but I have found none so far.

Comment: Update the question with these comments and where 'in-particular' you got stuck